# Filepath and it's URL variable is cut short when concatenated

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url

I have the following JQuery AJAX function:

```
function JQueryAJAXFunction(){
$input = document.getElementById("textInput").value;
console.log($input ); //Console output: "How to"
$('#resultsOutput').load('ajax/serverside/filepath.php?urlvariable='+$input);
}
```

It retrieves the value of $input from text field, which is a two letter word such as **"How to"** and displays it on the browser's console.

$input is then concatenated with the file path for the server side script and is assigned as a URL variable. However, in doing so the last word of $input -in this case "to"- disappears/is cut off.

Once the function is executed, the  URL variable on the server is retrieved and displayed using for example: `$_GET["urlvariable"]` It's value is as you can guess **"How"**.

What is the recommended solution to the problem? How can I get `$_GET["urlvariable"]` be equal to **"How to"**.

Comment: Maybe try `encodeURIComponent($input)`

Comment: It worked. If you mind posting it as an answer Ill gladly accept it as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain characters need to be encoded when used in URLs...a space is one of them. JavaScript provides a global function to encode any necessary characters for URLs - `encodeURIComponent`. Instead of just concatenating `$input`, you would concatenate:

```
encodeURIComponent($input)
```

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent